# Genetic Relationship Matrix

Tags: genetics

The classical definition of the Genetic Matrix

`G = ZZ'/2p(1-p)`

where Z = M - P

where P = 2(p-0.5)

I don't have a background in biology but understand Maths and Computer Science very well. I am trying to wrap my head around

1) Why do we define P the way we do?
2) Why do we subtract  P from M
3) How to interpret a negative entry in G?
4) Does the j,k element of G give me the genetic distance between j and k individuals?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. What is P? what is M? What is this genetic matrix suppose to represent? Is it a matrix of genetic variance and covariance for $n$ traits? Can you link to where you found those things?

Comment: Sure, here it is. http://nce.ads.uga.edu/wiki/lib/exe/fetch.php?media=uga_3_relationship.pdf

Comment: Any clarifications you could provide would be much appreciated.